# JPA Relation or Secondary Table

Tags: jpa, relation

I am reengineering one of my project with JPA which was initially on iBatis.

```
public class Entity{
    //ids and other stuff
    String locale;
    String text;
}
```

I was storing locale and text into separate table, which can be achieved via secondary table in JPA.

- I am not able to create secondary table with its own ids besides Join
  id?
- how can I achieve it? If possible then it raises the following
  question:
- how would I retrieve it back if I create an entity object with locale set to user settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables

Otherwise include your exact schema and model and issue.